# Delaunay triangulation with restrictions

Tags: delaunay

I need Delaunay triangulation (DT) but with one specific: not all points can be connected. In other words

bool Test( const Point & p0, const Point & p1 );

if this function returns false, then the edge between p0-p1 should NOT be created. There is a lot of info about DT in web, but what is a name for the case I need?

Thanks